# Do we have to manually update HTML files after MDC migration in the process of upgrading to Angular v15?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular15, angular-upgrade, mdc-components

Recently upgraded Angular app from v14 to v15, as per official update guide.
Then upgraded to Angular Material v15, which changed import statements to legacy based.
Then have migrated to MDC with the "ng generate @angular/material:mdc-migration", which has again updated all the legacy based imports back to regular Material imports.

This MDC migration step has automatically updated code in .scss, component.ts, spec.ts files but very few tags/elements in HTML files. And, this step has left many /*TODO(mdc-..... comments in all the scss/css files, which is actually the real pain/headache to us developers.

So my doubts are:

1.Should I manually update the html files i.e., template files to match with .mat-mdc class changes in scss files?

(Because in some of the MDC's automatic scss file changes, most of the css classes with .mat- have been changed to .mat-mdc-....e.g: .mat-checkbox is now .mat-mdc-checkbox, so I am really confused, about how does this match the  tags if only the css files class names are modified but not the HTML file element tags?)

2.Also, how would I know which material classes need to be updated to which new classes, in all the places where the MDC migration has left the TODO comments?
(there is no proper documentation to refer like old vs new as mentioned in this blog post (https://dev.to/bharathmuppa/complete-angular-mdc-migaration-guide-b3c))

3.Should I only be concerned about & only need to modify the places of TODO(mdc-... comments, or should I also modify spec.ts, .html, scss files to be in sync. Because, after MDC migration, most of my unit tests are failing :( .

So, dear senior devs, please shed some light on this queries and provide a solution. Thanks a lot in advance.